# jboss fuse xquery custom functions

Tags: apache-camel, xquery, jbossfuse

We have existing xqueries which we want to re use in our new JBoss fuse integration applications. As part of that I am trying to use XQuery component of JBoss Fuse 6.3. My question is how to pass arguments to my XQuery Function. This is my camel context

```
<camelContext id="dataConsumer-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:sql.properties"/>
    <route id="consumer-route">
        <from id="_from1" uri="activemq:queue:house"/>
        <log id="inputMessage" message="Got ${body}"/>
        <to id="_to1" uri="xquery:myXquery.xquery"/>
        <log id="transformedMessgae" message="Got ${body}"/>
        <to id="_to2" uri="sql:{{sql.insertIntoMessage}}"/>
        <log id="_log2" message="Message is inserted into DB"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

In myXquery.xquery this is the function I have

```
declare function xf:myPayments($pmtAddInp1 as element(ns0:PmtAddInp), 
   $header as element(*), $PaymentConstants as element(*)) as element() {   }

declare variable $pmtAddInp1 as element(ns0:PmtAddInp) external;
declare variable $header as element(*) external;
declare variable $PaymentConstants as element(*) external;
xf:myPayments($pmtAddInp1,$header,$PaymentConstants)
```

I really appreciate if anybody can answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the Camel Exchange is visible to your XQuery. For example, you can put the desired arguments as headers within your Camel Route, then within your XQuery you define them as `declare variable $in.headers.myArgumentKey as xs:string external;` and they will be available for your functions to use directly as a variable called `$in.headers.myArgumentKey`

Comment: Thanks Gerry for the response. Let me try that out

Comment: If you want to put xml into the message header, it depends on where the xml is coming from.  If the xml is in the exchange after using Camel to read it from a file, database, queue, or some other endpoint, you can just use `setHeader("parmName", simple("${body}"))' right in your camel route.  Or you can use a constant even like this: 'setHeader("parmName", constant("<myXML>Hello world</myXML>")).

Comment: xml which I want to pass as an argument to XQuery is in my classpath. I tried this but didn't work <setHeader headerName="pmtConstants" id="_setHeader1">
                <constant>classpath:PaymentConstants.xml</constant>
            </setHeader>

Comment: You have a few choices available to load resources from the classpath with Camel.  You can use the "Simple" language, and do something like this: `.setHeader("myXML").simple("resource:classpath:myXML.xml")` or with the language comp;onent: `.to("language:simple:classpath:foopath/myXML.xml")` then move it to the header or property you want.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I am able to set the xml in the header. But when I tried to use it in the xquery I am getting this error "Required item type of value of variable $in.headers.pmtConstants is element(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic". I declared that as "declare variable $in.headers.pmtConstants as element(*) external;" in my xquery.

Comment: Just take it in as string:  `declare variable $in.headers.pmtConstants as xs:string external;`  then convert it using the fn:parse-xml():  `let $pmtConstants := parse-xml($in.headers.pmtConstants)`  Then in your XQuery simply refer to it as `$pmtConstants`.

Comment: Thanks Gerry for the response. For some reason fn:parse-xml function is not getting recognized, I am trying to see if this issue is connected with XQuery version

Comment: i have same problem. my question is how to set this external variable in camel message header? My route is like below, i need to set message header for it for xquery declared external variable.I tried below approach, it does not work many thanks!

from("file:src/data?moveFailed=.error"). setHeader("variableName", simple("${body}"))to("xquery:myxquery.xq").to("file:target/output");

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gerry's answer:

body passes to XQuery component as root element.
Let say I have inbound body as

```
<Auth>
  <userName>JohnDoe</userName>
  <userPassword>abcd1234</userPassword>
</Auth>
```

then I can have XQuery to transform it and it may look like:

```
declare variable $in.headers.referenceId as xs:string external;

declare function transformRequest($requestBody as element()) as element() {

  <newRequest>
     <RqUID>{$in.headers.referenceId}</ser:RqUID>
     <UserPrincipal>{$requestBody/userName/text()}</UserPrincipal>
     <UserCredentials>{$requestBody/userPassword/text()}</UserCredentials>
  </newRequest>

};      

let $request := /*[1]
return buildNewRequest($request)
```

As you can see `let $request := /*[1]` sets internal variable `$request` to the root element of the message body.

PS. `$in.headers.referenceId` is a variable I can set into headers in Camel Route before calling my XQuery

Comment: Thanks Vadim for the response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: for simple constant values its working. I want to use a xml as an argument in my XQuery, any idea how to set a xml in header?

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Camel XQuery component for a long time. I prefer POJO format and work with Java objects instead. But, you may try to define external variable as element(), then pass header as DOMSource or DOM Node or such... header actually holds an Object and it can be anything... see you already got a problem to reuse old XQueries... that is one of the many reasons why I'm not going this way. Maybe rewrite them in Java is much more simplest way rather then do many tricks to make them working... and performance is a main concern. It is not comparable with Java at all.